# Android raised button text color

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm trying to style my app theme.
I'm using Android 7, AppCompat v24 and Xamarin, but I think that the latter is not affecting the problem I'm facing.

I'm trying to style my buttons using this guide:
http://www.materialdoc.com/raised-button/

This is my theme:

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialog</item>
```

the button style:

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
```

and this is my button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"           
        android:theme="@style/MyButton"/>
```

The problem is that in the link, when the button is styled, the text color is white, while in my project it remains black.
If I add `android:textColor="@color/white"` to my button, I get the white text, but it doesn't react anymore to enable-disabled state. The button looks the same in both states and the text color doesn't change to a lighter gray, like it does in the example.
I would like to get the same result as the one described in the link. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: try with `style=` instead of `android:theme=`. It can be hard to find which to use but you might find something [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Attributes).
Also, for completeness post the MyButton style declaration.

Comment: sorry, I added the button style.
Using style instead of android:theme makes the button ignore the background color (it turns gray as default). It also changes the text font to lower case.

Comment: Try changing the parent of `MyButton` to `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` and also add the textColor white there.

Comment: Same black text as before on the button!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>`in your button style

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: Same behaviour as described above: the text alwais remains white, whether the button is enable or not.